# How to stop a timer when mouse is scrolling or on top of scrollbar in listbox

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar

I'm looking for a way to detect and switch off a timer when the mouse cursor is scrolling a listbox.
There is an easy way despite to create a new class like this one?[link](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/414887/what-is-listbox-scroll-move-event)

Would be possible to check rectangle location of listbox 1 scroll bar and say: if mouse is in this range then timer1.stop?

EDIT1:
In order to create a rectangle I'm using

```
 If e.X >= 364 AndAlso e.X <= 446 AndAlso e.Y >= 86 AndAlso e.Y <= 144 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked within the rectangle")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Clicked outside the rectangle")
    End If
```

449-359 are the Top left corner location of the rectangle
while the rectangle size is x30 y156
The problem is I don't know in which event let it run!
Listbox click event doesn't recognize scrollbar as "inside of listbox"
Form_mouse click event doesn't recognize listbox scroll bar as a click in the form.
There is an event that despite the control you are on, it will let you play with this workaround?
Thanks

Comment: Short answer: yes. Look at [PointToScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen?view=netcore-3.1) method and the [MouseMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove?view=netcore-3.1) event

Comment: I Am having issues. I'm updating the question.

Comment: As I said, use the MouseMove event

Comment: Tried already, It doesn't recognize when It's on top of listbox scrollbar. It will recognize just when outside of those limits.

Comment: Then you use the wron x and y. Have you used PointToScreen to get the actual position?

Comment: no, I'm  using form as location limits. In this way I'm taking the coordinates: I select the form location and I grab the coordinates. To be sure, I add a panel in order to grab the location and then I add the size of it. so for example if panel locations are: 364-82 and the size is : 82-62, then I'm simply adding x+x and y+y it will become: 446-144. I 'm updating the main code with those coordinates . Hope not to be wrong about how to take the coordinates. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I posted [on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0900e71d-b755-44e9-af50-0f6622fe88ce/stop-a-timer-when-user-is-scrollingdragging-listbox-scrollbar?forum=vbgeneral) using [this C# code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/46d8cba4-1266-4f39-a27b-5e86a4cf3583/listbox-verticle-scroll-bar-event?forum=Vsexpressvcs). There is no code presented below that will restart the Timer.

```
Public Class BetterListBox
    Inherits ListBox

    ' Event declaration
    Public Delegate Sub BetterListBoxScrollDelegate(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As BetterListBoxScrollArgs)
    Public Event Scroll As BetterListBoxScrollDelegate
    ' WM_VSCROLL message constants
    Private Const WM_VSCROLL As Integer = &H115
    Private Const SB_THUMBTRACK As Integer = 5
    Private Const SB_ENDSCROLL As Integer = 8

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        ' Trap the WM_VSCROLL message to generate the Scroll event
        MyBase.WndProc(m)

        If m.Msg = WM_VSCROLL Then
            Dim nfy As Integer = m.WParam.ToInt32() And &HFFFF
            If (nfy = SB_THUMBTRACK OrElse nfy = SB_ENDSCROLL) Then
                RaiseEvent Scroll(Me, New BetterListBoxScrollArgs(Me.TopIndex, nfy = SB_THUMBTRACK))
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Class BetterListBoxScrollArgs
        ' Scroll event argument
        Private mTop As Integer
        Private mTracking As Boolean
        Public Sub New(ByVal top As Integer, ByVal tracking As Boolean)
            mTop = top
            mTracking = tracking
        End Sub
        Public ReadOnly Property Top() As Integer
            Get
                Return mTop
            End Get
        End Property
        Public ReadOnly Property Tracking() As Boolean
            Get
                Return mTracking
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Class
```

Then in your form subscribe to the Scroll event. Requires the ListBox above in your project, one Timer enabled and a Label.

```
Private Sub BetterListBox1_Scroll(Sender As Object, e As BetterListBox.BetterListBoxScrollArgs) _
    Handles BetterListBox1.Scroll

    Timer1.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label1.Text = Now.ToString()
End Sub
```