# How to add a form2 control on top of a form1.control

Tags: vb.net, controls

I have two forms. Form1 with richtextbox and form2 with listbox.

I'd like to put listbox on top of richtextbox, docking it.
I want to do exactly like this:

- `form2.Controls.Remove(ListBox1)`
- `form2.hide`
- `form1.richtextbox1.controls.add(form2.listbox1)`
- `form1.richtextbox1.hide 'I can't hide, also listbox will hide...`
- `form2.listbox1.location= richtextbox1` or
- `form2.listbox1.bounds=richtextbox1.bounds`

Everything works until setting form2.listbox1.location as If richtextbox1 is hidden also listbox will be. Also, setting location and/or bounds of listbox the same as richtextbox is not completely covering the richtextbox. I also tried using the same size for both.

[Gif Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3YAx.gif)

Comment: you need 1 form. May be, table layout panel

Comment: Sounds to me like a single form, maybe with a tab control (One tab containing the rich text box and on containing the list box)  Or a user control maybe.  It's not the normal practice to be adding controls from another form

Comment: I updated the question, probably now it's more clear.

Comment: Why are you adding it to the richtextbox?  Add it to the FORM: `form1.controls.add(form2.listbox1)`.  You don't need to remove it from Form2 beforehand, either...it'll just move automatically.

Comment: because I want to display it on top of richtextbox. basically richtextbox will not longer exist until listbox is on top of it. On top also of scrollbar.

Comment: I added a gif for better understanding

Comment: "Also, setting location and/or bounds of listbox the same as richtextbox is not completely covering the richtextbox."  If you add the ListBox to the RichTextBox, then the Location for the ListBox to make it in the top left would be (0, 0).  Then set its size to be the same as the RichTextBox.  Locations are relative to the parent.

Comment: Hi @Idle_Mind can you be a bit clearer? would you be able to answer so I can accept it as answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim LB As ListBox = Form2.ListBox1
    If IsNothing(LB.Tab)
        LB.Tag = LB.Size ' <-- store it for later use
    End If
    Me.Controls.Add(LB)
    LB.Bounds = RichTextBox1.Bounds
    RichTextBox1.Hide()
End Sub
```

Later, when you move the ListBox back, retrieve the size stored in the Tag:

```
If Not IsNothing(LB.Tab)
    LB.Size = LB.Tag
End If
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Idle_Mind,  LB.Location = New Point(0, 0) would set its location at the top left right? Richtextbox  is not located in 0;0. Would it be possible to retrieve location and size of richtextbox before to replace it with listbox?

Comment: It will be in the top left of the RICHTEXTBOX because that is its PARENT.  Like I said, the `.Location` property is relatively to the parent.

Comment: The RichtTextBox could be anywhere in the form.  If the ListBox is added to the RichTextBox, then (0, 0) will still be the top left of the RichTextBox, even if you moved the RTB.

Comment: I had right now time to try your code and still there are problems. Look at this gif [link](https://imgur.com/a/Ixj9V6q) , under button3 there is your code.

Comment: In my testing, the ListBox was the SAME height as the RTB.   BUT...if the text in the richtextbox is longer than the RTB, then you'll still be able to scroll the RTB down to see that text.  Do you really need the ListBox INSIDE the RTB?  Why not make the ListBox the same size as the RTB, add the ListBox to the Form, the hide the RTB?  What is the use for this setup?

Comment: Hi Idle I just sow your update.. How is that possible?

Comment: We just need to figure out what is DIFFERENT about your setup.  There's something you haven't described yet that is the key to us understanding how to fix it.  Give more details.

Comment: Hi Idle, nothing is really changing. The only thing is that richtextbox is inside of a groupbox, but I don't think it really change. Look at this : [link](https://imgur.com/a/GlIW2qK) .
Betterlistbox is a listbox class which contains Scroll event too. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137614/how-to-stop-a-timer-when-mouse-is-scrolling-or-on-top-of-scrollbar-in-listbox) so I don't think this is the problem. Thanks

Comment: "The only thing is that richtextbox is inside of a groupbox"  That's the difference!  So instead of adding the ListBox to the Form with `Me.Controls.Add(LB)`, you'd instead add it to the GroupBox, whatever name that is: `GroupBox1.Controls.Add(LB)`

Comment: Correct!! Thanks! But how it is even possible?I thought form1.controls.add would refer to all the controls in the form area, despite their position or what they are inside of.

Comment: No.  The Controls() collection only gives you the controls that are DIRECTLY contained by that container.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the original size of listbox?

Comment: No, but you could store the original size in the `.Tag` property before the initial move.  Added some code snippets above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Form2.Listbox1.Parent = Form1
Form1.RichTextBox1.Visible = false
Form2.Listbox1.dock = DockStyle.Fill
```

The cool thing here is any code written in Form2 for Listbox1 will still function while it's sitting in Form1.

P.S. Rename your controls.

Comment: This is not displaying the listbox on top of richtextbox.Note also that I can't hide richtextbox if I m going to add listbox as a control in it.

Comment: I added a gif for better understanding